# Sutta in which Buddha says that he/anyone don't have to take another person words?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, sutras

As in Title,
I'm searching for a sutta in which I recall that probably some person started to offend a Buddha, and he responded by giving some analogy, probably to offered food, that one doesn't have to take another persons words, offenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was in the [Akkosa Sutta SN 7.2](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn07/sn07.002.than.html)

This incident took place when the Blessed One was staying near Rajagaha in the Bamboo Grove, the Squirrels’ Sanctuary. The angry young man was a brahman called Akkosaka Bharadvaja. He has heard that a brahman of the Bharadvaja clan had gone forth from the home life into homelessness in the presence of the Blessed One. That is why angered & displeased, he went to the Blessed One and, on arrival, insulted & cursed him with rude, harsh words.

When this was said, the Blessed One said to him: “What do you think, brahman: Do friends & colleagues, relatives & kinsmen come to you as guests?”

“Yes, Master Gotama, sometimes friends & colleagues, relatives & kinsmen come to me as guests.”

“And what do you think: Do you serve them with staple & non-staple foods & delicacies?”

“Yes, sometimes I serve them with staple & non-staple foods & delicacies.”

“And if they don’t accept them, to whom do those foods belong?”

“If they don’t accept them, Master Gotama, those foods are all mine.”

“In the same way, brahman, that with which you have insulted me, who is not insulting; that with which you have taunted me, who is not taunting; that with which you have berated me, who is not berating: that I don’t accept from you. It’s all yours, brahman. It’s all yours.

“Whoever returns insult to one who is insulting, returns taunts to one who is taunting, returns a berating to one who is berating, is said to be eating together, sharing company, with that person. But I am neither eating together nor sharing your company, brahman. It’s all yours. It’s all yours.”